# Liquibase diff gives constraint error

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I get this error when I try with both command line and Maven invocations:

```
Diff Results:
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown constraint type: 3
```

This is using a SQL Server DB. Created both the reference and target using liquibase:update.

Properties:

```
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:11433;databaseName=DB 
username=user
password=pass
referenceUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:11433;databaseName=DBRef
referenceUsername=user
referencePassword=pass
```

Comment: Please run again with logLevel set to DEBUG and include the contents of the log file. My suspicion is that you have an "oldish" version of Liquibase and a "newish" version of MS SQL Server and there is some new constraint type that the older Liquibase doesn't know about. If you run with debug I think it will show the query used to get the constraints, but I am not certain of that.

Answer (score 3):

We use a combination of ***Liquibase***/***MS-SQL database*** and had a similar issue when we recently upgraded our driver to Microsoft's latest release (6.4.0.jre8).

As @SteveDonie says in his comment, the issue is with "oldish" version of liquibase and "newish" version of MS-SQL driver. Details behind the reason for this problem can be found in this liquibase JIRA case:
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3141

To solve this, we tried upgrading the liquibase version to the latest as on date (3.6.1) and it works!! You may also try to downgrade the version of your MS-SQL driver, but I would say that isn't a good option - it's better to upgrade than downgrade unless you've some pressing needs to that.